# java constructor handling lack of arguments

Tags: java

i have this code here for a person details and the person should be intialized always whatever the number of possible arguments given ,like for example only height and age or salary and age
and i find it difficult to declare a constructor for every combination of arguments , is there a more optimal solution than that ??

```
class person {
    public static final int defalut_salary=1000;
    public static final int default_age=20;
    public static final double default_height=6;
    public static final String default_name="jack";

    protected int salary;
    protected int age;
    protected double height;
    protected String name;  

    person(){       
    }
}
```

Comment: The builder pattern could solve your problem.

Comment: You could use a Map as parameter and then you'll only need one constructor. This is how Groovy implements named parameters.

Comment: What does this have to do with performance, by the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Builder` pattern:

```
public final class Person {
    private final int salary;
    private final int age;
    private final double height;
    private final String name;

    public Person(int salary, int age, double height, String name) {
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters or whatever you want

    public static class Builder {
        // Make each field default appropriately
        private int salary = 1000;
        private int age = 20;
        private double height = 6;
        private String name = "jack";

        public Builder setSalary(int salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
            return this;
        }

        // Ditto for other properties

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(salary, age, height, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Person person = new Person.Builder().setAge(25).setHeight(15).build();
```

You can perform validation in the `Person` constructor, and if you want to make any of the fields *mandatory*, you could take those in the `Builder` constructor.

Comment: Using the builder-pattern instead of a flexible constructor like I suggested requires more verbose code in both the implementation and the code which uses it. But the advantage is that the invocation is a lot more readable. When you have a constructor taking multiple arguments it can be hard to tell which argument does what, but with the builder pattern it's obvious which method of the builder sets what attribute.

Comment: @Christian: The code was already valid and how I wanted it to be - the `Builder` class is a nested class within `Person`. With your change, the usage at the bottom would have been invalid. It's fairly common (in my experience) to nest the builder for a type within the type itself.

Comment: Woops - sorry. Thanks for correcting me there and rolling back my changes! Now that I look at it closer I see my mistake, too!

Answer (score 0):

You could define the constructor to take primitive wrapper classes (like java.lang.Integer or java.lang.Double) instead of primitives. The difference is that this allows you to pass `null` instead of a value. You can then check them for `null`. When they are null, you assign the default value. When they aren't, you assign their value.

```
public Person(Integer salary, Integer age, Double height, String name) {
    if (salary == null) this.salary = salary else this.salary = default_salary;
    if (age == null) this.age = age else this.age = default_age;
    //...
}
```

The invocation `new Person(1200, null, 5.3, null);` would mean "create a person with start salary 1200, default age, height 5.3 and default name".

Another approach is to use the [builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) as shown in the answer by Jon Skeet. It is less concise, but more readable.

Comment: Your "if-else" misses a semicolons and doesn't feel like Java (here `?:` is both shorter and clearer).

Comment: @maaartinus I intentionally avoided the ternary-operator because OP is obviously inexperienced, and inexperienced developers are often confused by it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all fields in a default constructor and use methods to set values in the desired fields, for example like this:

```
class A{
    Field a;
    Field b;
    Field c;

    public A(){
        a = SOME_VALUE;
        b = SOME_VALUE;
        c = SOME_VALUE;
    }

    public A withA(Field a){ this.a = a; return this; }
    public A withB(Field b){ this.b = b; return this; }
    public A withC(Field c){ this.c = c; return this; }

    /* other code */
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
A a = new A().withB(SOME_OTHER_VALUE).withC(YET_DIFFERENT_VALUE);
```

If don't want the fields' values to be changed with subsequent calls to `withX()` methods, you can use a full-fledged builder pattern.

Comment: Note that many people expect `withX` to create a new object like [Lombok's Wither](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html) does. I'd go for `setX`.